# Android: passing extra to intent - can't receive what I've passed

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to do a simple thing: pass a variable from activity A to activity B. I have this method in activity A:

```
private void editAccount(CloudAccount account) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditAccountActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("accountId", account.getId());
    this.showToast("ID passed: " + account.getId());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Toast in this code shows "ID passed: 1". This is correct.
Now, I am starting activity B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Toast.makeText(this, "ID received: " + extras.getString("accountId"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This toast shows "ID received: null". This is not correct. If I test getInt("accountId") - it returns 0.
What is wrong with my code? It seems to be very simple, no place for mistake, but still...

Comment: This does looks ok.. What happens if you first save the int and then display it?
int value = extras.getInt("accountId");
and show with:

    Toast.makeText(this, "ID received: " + String.valueOf(value), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: What type does `account.getId()` return?

Comment: it is long: public long getId()

Comment: "if you first save the int and then display it" - the same. String.valueOf(value) shows 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was stupid question, actually. I was passing long to extras, while was trying to receive int. getLong() worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use:

```
public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)
```

Or in the case where you are using a Bundle

```
public int getInt (String name)
```

Comment: @Camper In the context of your code, you could use `Integer.toString(extras.getInt("accountId"))`.

Comment: I am using getInt(). It returns 0, while should be 1. getString() returns null - see my original question. It is irrelevant if I use getInt() or Integer.toString() - the problem is this value does not get to my intent, it is lost somewhere :)

Comment: Ah, in the code, it is shown as getString(), but it seems you have solved your own issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to pass data from current activity to next activity. You need to put some codes like below in your Activity A.

```
 private void editAccount(CloudAccount account) { 
      SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditAccountActivity.class);  
      editor.putInt("accountId", account.getId()); editor.commit();    
      startActivity(intent); 
 }
```

After that you need to put this codes at your Activity B to receive your ID from Activity A.

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
int id;

preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);

id =  preferences.getString("accountId", 0);
```

Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a **Integer** value to an Activity, you must get that value in other intent as

```
 empid = Extras.getInt(String str);
```

In your case you must use as

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
System.out.println("Received value is "+extras.getInt("accountId"));
Toast.makeText(this, "ID received: " + extras.getInt("accountId"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can check logcat for received value now. Good luck